# HOW TO CHANGE THE MATLAB UI LANGUAGE?

Tags: matlab

Few months back, when I was using Matlab 2017b version, i found that the Matlab display language has changed from English to some language (which I still don't know). So I thought there is some issue with the version so I downloaded Matlab 2020b and still I am facing the same issue (please see the screenshot attached for reference). And yes,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLK10.png)I have tried changing the region and also adding "MWLOCALE_TRANSLATED" into system variables.

[CHANGED DISPLAY LANGUAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc8f6.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/474183-changing-windows-font-leaves-matlab-ui-unreadable

Comment: Hi Tushant! This sounds like a job for MathWorks Tech Support. Open a case with them by emailing support@mathworks.com. BTW, seems to me like that's not just that Matlab is displaying the wrong language: the strings in the UI in your screenshot there don't look like sensible words in any language to me; that seems like more of a character encoding or font issue than a simple language/locale setting. Your Matlab is hosed. ;) Are you using a non-English Windows installation? In Preferences > Fonts, what's your "Desktop text font"?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe your Matlab font settings have gotten messed up. Try resetting your Matlab preferences by:

- Exit all your Matlab sessions.
- Open Windows File Explorer, go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks` (by typing that in the address bar near the top of the window), and delete the entire `MATLAB` folder under there.
- Restart Matlab.

Comment: Darn it. Time to contact MathWorks Tech Support.